# Matlab standalone executive without pause

Tags: matlab

When I try a very simple Matlab standalone executive file from the dos-promt,
the program pauses in the end of it and I have to press enter to exit.
I understand why its so (if I would dubble klick on the file in windows the cmd is disappearing before I coult see anything)
But now its annoying.
How can I get rid of that?

Comment: Did you try running `exit()` at the end of your function?

Comment: Good idea, unfortunately that did not work... maybe some compiler flag?

Comment: No that is not the same! I make an exe file not rum matlab throu terminal

Comment: I think this may be more a question of how your OS handles it than of how the program is built. I just built a program containing `'hello' pause(1) 'goodbye'` and compiled this as a console application. When double clicking this in windows, it opened, showed me what I expected, and closed automatically.